# How to reference a scss filepath in rails 6/webpacker?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-6, webpacker, precompile

I'm looking for a way to reference a specific file in JavaScript/stylesheets both in development and production. Just like the helper asset_path does with asset pipeline, but I can't find anything in the webpacker documentation more than stylesheet_pack_tag which returns a html link tag.

Is there a simple way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Helper asset_pack_path did the trick.